# Filter torch tensor based on another tensor without loops

Tags: python, pytorch

Suppose I have the following two torch.Tensors:

```
x = torch.tensor([0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2], dtype=torch.int64)
y = torch.tensor([0,2], dtype=torch.int64)
```

I want to somehow filter `x` such that only the values that are in `y` remain:

```
x_filtered = torch.tensor([0,0,0,2,2,2,2])
```

For another example, if `y = torch.tensor([0,1])`, then `x_filtered = torch.tensor([0,0,0,1,1])`. Both `x,y` are always 1D and int64. `y` is always sorted, if it makes it simpler, we can assume that `x` is always sorted as well.

I tried to think of various ways to do it without using loops, but failed. I cannot really use loops because my use case involves `x` in the millions and `y` in tens of thousands. Any help is appreciated.

---

Just realised what I need is the torch equivalent of `numpy.in1d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filtering tensor as you want in you task, you need to use isin function available in torch. The way it is used is given below:-

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor([0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3], dtype=torch.int64)
y = torch.tensor([0,2], dtype=torch.int64)
# torch.isin(x, y)
c=x[torch.isin(x,y)]
print(c)
```

After running this code you will get your preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.isin.html?highlight=isin#torch.isin:

```
>>> torch.isin(x,y)
tensor([ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```